# Install Python 3.5 with pip on Debian 8

Tags: python, debian

so, my question is **very** simple, how can I install Python 3.5 with pip on Debian 8, **without** getting errors like `ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest way I've found to install Python (though I haven't tried Debian 8) on Linux is to use the python distribution [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).

```
# Assuming you want 64bit
cd ~
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
# Agree to the license agreement and where to put it
# Add it to your $PATH
# Assuming you use bash (You might have to change this if my memory isn't correct...)
echo 'export PATH="~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
# reload your .bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# make sure it works
python --version # should print out 3.5
# install something with pip
pip install pyperclip # or anything
# make sure it works
python -c 'import pyperclip'
```

Now you can use pip. However, for complicated binary packages like numpy, etc., Miniconda also comes with a tool called `conda`. `conda --help` or google should get you started down that route if you need it.

If you ever need to uninstall Miniconda, just erase `~/miniconda3` and remove the `PATH` line mentioned above from your `~/.bashrc`

Also, if you have the room and you want a lot of pre-installed packages that 'just work', they also put out [Anaconda python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

If you aren't used the terminal, Anaconda comes with a decent IDE, [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/), which can by started by typing `spyder` from the terminal.