# install matplotlib from source using python3.5

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.5

I try to install matplotlib1.5.1 from source using python3.5 in CentOS7:

git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib

/opt/custom_python_path/bin/python3.5 setup.py install

I get the below error:

```
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,--rpath=/opt/pythonlatest/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/ft2font.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/ft2font_wrapper.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/mplutils.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/opt/pythonlatest/lib -lfreetype -lpython3.5m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/matplotlib/ft2font.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.5m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython3.5m.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

How else to make: setup.py install pick from /opt/custom_python_path/bin/python3.5?

The prominent error is:

> recompile with -fPIC

Thanks

Comment: If, like me in the past, you're looking at installing from source because the package manager is letting you down, checkout [anaconda/miniconda python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It's package manager, `conda` lets you easily install binaries as part of your python library dependencies. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385423/install-python-3-5-with-pip-on-debian-8/35385656#35385656) an answer I wrote about how to do it.

Comment: CentOS.7 ships with python2.7.5 installed at /usr/bin...usr/lib....I have installed python 3.5 in /opt/custom_python_path/ . I would like to know how to build the matplotlib1.5.1 successfully by making it to take binaries from /opt/custom_python_path/lib instead of /usr/lib. ./configure for python itself has --enable-shared option...howabout the setup.py that ships with matplotlib...does it have similar options like LDFLAGS and --enable-shared?

Comment: I'm not sure about the custom compilation flags, but if you just want a modern (and easily uninstallable) python that can easily install matplotlib, give miniconda a try