# How to install Python 3.5 on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

I need to install Python 3.5+ on Rasbian (Debian for the Raspberry Pi). Currently only version 3.4 is supported. For the sources I want to compile I have to install:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3 python-empy python3-dev python3-empy python3-nose python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-vcstool pydocstyle pyflakes python3-coverage python3-mock python3-pep8
```

But I think that `apt-get` will install more than these packages, for example `libpython3-dev`.

I already install `python3` from https://www.python.org/downloads/ but I think, that is not complete.

Can you give me some suggestion which way is the best to get this?

A similar question was posted here [Install Python 3.5 with pip on Debian 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385423/install-python-3-5-with-pip-on-debian-8) but this solution seems not to work on arm64.

---

Edit:

regarding to the comment of Padraic Cunningham: The first step I have done before. The second one results into this:

```
$ sudo python3.5 get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19177, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpoe3rjlw3/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpoe3rjlw3/pip.zip/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpoe3rjlw3/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpoe3rjlw3/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpoe3rjlw3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpoe3rjlw3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 66, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'
```

Comment: http://bohdan-danishevsky.blogspot.ie/2015/10/building-python-35-on-raspberry-pi-2.html

Comment: Consider posting on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ for questions like this.

Comment: You need to install libssl header files, sudo apt-get install libssl-dev and recompile python3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The suggestion of @Padraic Cunningham to install `libssl` header files was helpful.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

But after this I further had to install *GCC* higher version 5 and *CMake* higher 3.5. The new *Raspian Stretch* comes with *Python 3.5* and additionally with *GCC 6.1* and *CMake 3.5*.

So the easiest way was to upgrade my system to Stretch (at the moment under test):

```
sudo echo 'deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing main contrib non-free rpi' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This is quiet easy and always up to date. At the end this is my prefered solution :)

Comment: Perfect! Saved me tons of frustration.

Comment: I had the same problem, after using this solution the embedded wireless adapter isn't recognized. Cannot find device "wlan0"

Comment: Sometimes the interface got an other name.

Answer (score 15):

Head over to the *RaspberryPi stackexchange* and follow [these instructions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/56632/17798). To summarize:

```sh
sudo apt-get install build-essential libc6-dev
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev
sudo apt-get install libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev
cd $HOME
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/Python-3.8.6.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.8.6.tgz
cd Python-3.8.6
./configure       # 3 min 13 s
# Let's use 4 threads
make -j4          # 8 min 29 s
sudo make install # ~ 4 min
cd ..
sudo rm -fr ./Python-3.8.6*
# upgrade:
sudo pip3 install -U pip
sudo pip3 install -U setuptools
```

(Note: he approximate times shown were measurements for the older python 3.5.2.)

Comment: This solution was better for me because it allows me to stay on the stable raspbian release

Comment: Why do you not concatenate those commands as in summarize all apt-get into one line and concat the rest with &&?

Comment: @Zurechtweiser Primarily for readability and secondly because some are more commonly and already installed than others. Also, if one errors, you will easily loose track of which one was installed, and which wasn't.