# Issue using psutil (Python Module) on RasPi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

i would like to install the psutil module to read the CPU data. Unfortunately after the installation the following is still displayed when the code is executed.

`import psutil
ImportError: No module named 'psutil'`

As I have seen, the installation was done in the Python 2.7 folder. However, I use python 3.5 in the shell as well as in Thonny. 
This question has already been answered on stackoverflow, but I could not solve it with the given information.

How do I install psutil for Python 3.5?

I already installed it with...

```
sudo apt-get install python3-psutil
```

so also ...

`apt-get install python3-psutil`

tried it out. The second option indicated that the root directory could not be locked.

What is the correct way to use the Psutil module?

BG and Thank you!

Comment: [How to download and install Python 3.5 in Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/54365/50099), [How to install Python 3.5 on Raspbian Jessie](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39089698/608639), etc.

Comment: It is not about the installation of python. It's about the module that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved it.

The command to enter is:

`sudo pip3 install psutil`

now the module runs with Python 3